# Global inbox email says "updates every 3 hours", linked page says "daily updates"

Tags: bug, global-inbox, email, email-notification

It's only a small one, but I just got an email notifying me of an item in my inbox. The footer shows:

[image]

However, when I click the link, the page looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the email states that the emails are "every 3 hours" while the unsubscribe page states "daily updates"